# How to refactor a shell function to avoid duplicating code?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have two shell scripts which run one by one sequentially .
Everything all parameter  is same except `BUCKETNAME`
Is there any way to refactor this in such a way that in one command only i can run this .
Here is the both command that i am running to execute .

Command 1

```
jsonDumpFL()
{
  cat <<EOF
{
   "QUEUEURL":"",
   "BUCKETREGION":"us-east-1",
   "FLAGFILE":"",
   "FTPUSERID":"pcfp-test",
   "FTPPATH":"/PCFP/Incr1",
   "FTPPASSWORD":"pcfp-test",
   "PARAMETERSTOREREGION":"us-east-1",
   "ISFTP2S3":"false",
   "FTPSERVER":"11.11.11.11",
   "BUCKETNAME":"FinancialLineItem/FINALSPARK",
   "QUEUEREGION":"",
   "ISSFTPENABLED":"false",
   "LOCALPATH":"path"
}
EOF
}

aws apigateway test-invoke-method --rest-api-id  int1234udj --resource-id  1asde1 --http-method POST --body "$(jsonDumpFL)"
```

Command 2

```
jsonDumpSEG()
{
  cat <<EOF
{
   "QUEUEURL":"",
   "BUCKETREGION":"us-east-1",
   "FLAGFILE":"",
   "FTPUSERID":"pcfp-test",
   "FTPPATH":"/PCFP/Incr1",
   "FTPPASSWORD":"pcfp-test",
   "PARAMETERSTOREREGION":"us-east-1",
   "ISFTP2S3":"false",
   "FTPSERVER":"11.11.11.11",
   "BUCKETNAME":"Segments/FINALSPARK",
   "QUEUEREGION":"",
   "ISSFTPENABLED":"false",
   "LOCALPATH":"path"
}
EOF
}

aws apigateway test-invoke-method --rest-api-id  int1234udj --resource-id  1asde1 --http-method POST --body "$(jsonDumpSEG)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply re-factor your function to take one argument that's the value of `BUCKETNAME` and change your function name to make it dynamic

```
jsonDump()
{
  cat <<-EOF
{
   "QUEUEURL":"",
   "BUCKETREGION":"us-east-1",
   "FLAGFILE":"",
   "FTPUSERID":"pcfp-test",
   "FTPPATH":"/PCFP/Incr1",
   "FTPPASSWORD":"pcfp-test",
   "PARAMETERSTOREREGION":"us-east-1",
   "ISFTP2S3":"false",
   "FTPSERVER":"11.11.11.11",
   "BUCKETNAME":"$1",
   "QUEUEREGION":"",
   "ISSFTPENABLED":"false",
   "LOCALPATH":"path"
}
EOF
}
```

and now call your function as

```
"$(jsonDump "FinancialLineItem/FINALSPARK")"
```

or as

```
"$(jsonDump "Segments/FINALSPARK")"
```

Answer (score 1):

`jq` is a better option for creating dynamic JSON, as it ensures your parameter will be correctly quoted.

```
jsonDump () {
   jq -n --argjson bn "$1" '{
        QUEUEURL: "",
        BUCKETREGION: "us-east-1",
        FLAGFILE: "",
        FTPUSERID: "pcfp-test",
        FTPPATH: "/PCFP/Incr1",
        FTPPASSWORD: "pcfp-test",
        PARAMETERSTOREREGION: "us-east-1",
        ISFTP2S3: "false",
        FTPSERVER: "11.11.11.11",
        BUCKETNAME: $bn,
        QUEUEREGION: "",
        ISSFTPENABLED: "false",
        LOCALPATH: "path"
    }'
}
```

(It also lets you drop the quotes around the object keys if they don't contain any "special" characters.)